# Chart.js with data from database

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

since 2 hours I'm trying a simple thing: displaying data from database with Chart.js. I've checked like 4 tutorials, viewed 3 SO-Threads, but nothing is working as intented to. Don't know if its just a minor problem or what the problem is...

So what I'm trying is the following:

`stats.php`:

```
<script>
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "stats_api.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: data,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Anzahl Asservate",
        backgroundColor: [getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor(),getRandomColor()],
        data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Kategorien-Verteilung der Asservate'
      }
    }
});
}
});
});
</script>
```

`stats_api.php`:

```
<?php

require 'databaseConnection.php';

$datumStart = "2010-12-19 08:38:32";
$datumEnde = "2019-12-19 08:38:32";

$v_rp_ass_kat = $database->query("
select s.* from (select @DatumStart:='$datumStart',@DatumEnde:='$datumEnde') parm , v_rp_ass_kat s;")->fetchAll();

$labels = [];

foreach($v_rp_ass_kat as $element){
    array_push($labels, $element[2]);
}

echo json_encode($labels);
```

The `json_encode` is returning this:

```
["Mobiltelefon","Smartphone","SIM-Karte","Tablet","Navigationsger\u00e4t","USB-Stick","Speicherkarte","PC","Notebook","Festplatte"]
```

With that, I'm getting the error saying `data.labels.map is not a function`.

I also tried it without the foreach in php, instead a `json_encode` of `$v_rp_ass_kat` and then do a

```
labels = [];
for(var i in data){
    labels.push(data[i].kategorie);
}
```

But this somehow splits the array into single letters, so instead of 10 labels with one word each, I get like 100 labels, one for every letter of the json array...

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle somehow?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao hard to... how can I get the data from my database in the fiddle..?

Comment: Just hardcode it as is..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao trying to since 10 minutes, but can't get it working, getting an error from chart js saying something about offset, somethings missing..

Comment: Atleast some sample dummy fiddle will help us to get started with.. :(

Comment: @GuruprasadRao well, this is what I got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/bf4v9272/3/, but it doesn't work at all so far..

Comment: Ok.. Let me see what I can do..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reckon, you're getting the response as a string and passing it to the `labels` property, while it expects an array of strings. *(same mistake in your fiddle as well)*

To convert that response string to an array, you can use [**`JSON.parse()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
...
data: {
      labels: JSON.parse(data),
      ...
```

also, you should use the chart.js version 2.x, as you're using it's syntax.

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bf4v9272/5/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dyclassroom.com/chartjs/chartjs-how-to-draw-bar-graph-using-data-from-mysql-table-and-php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var player = [];
        var score = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            player.push("Player " + data[i].playerid);
            score.push(data[i].score);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: player,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: 'Player Score',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: score
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartdata
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});

i hope you will Get

Comment: That actually was one of the tutorials I tried to work with, but which didn't work for me, as lines with the `for....in..` did split into letters, not into the elements..